# HTML button vs progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking at an existing website, and I am trying to make some changes. I am trying to create a progress bar with some clicking capabilities.

For example, 
in the CSS file, the playbutton class is defined as this:

```
.playButton{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 41px;
    height: 41px;
    left: 595px;
    top: 19px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

in the index.html, I can see this class is used like this:

```
<div class="playButton">
    <a href="#" id="playMe1">
        <img src="images/playButton.png" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

and in the JavaScript file, I can see this:

```
$('#playMe1').on('click',function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#pauseMe1').show();
    audioElement.play();
});
```

(I made sure that no place else defines any sort of special hovering function)

Now, when I load the website, I can see that when my mouse is hovering over the "playMe1" button, the mouse "arrow"-shape, turns to a "hand"-shape, which indicates that I can click on the button. And, in fact, when I click on it, it does play the track.

Then I tried to add a progress bar, to monitor the progress of a playing track, and I was successful in doing that.
And, then I tried to get more interactive, and tried to have the option for the user to be able to click on the progress bar, and change the progress bar percentage, by clicking on it.

So, in the CSS file, I defined this:

```
.progressBar { 
   border:1px solid #aaa; 
   color:#fff; 
   width:295px; 
   height:5px;
}
.progress {
   background-color:#ff0000;
   height:5px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Then, I added this to the html file:

```
<div class="progressBar">
    <a href="#" id="progressBar1">
        <span class="progress" id="progress1"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And, just as a test, I tried to test out my simple change, by coding the following in the JavaScript file:

```
$('#progressBar1').on('click',function() {
    var progress = document.getElementById("progress1");
    progress.style.width = 70 + "%";
});
```

But, I don't know why I am not able to click on the progress bar ?!?
I was expecting to see the mouse shape changes from "arrow" to "hand" when I was hovering over the progress bar, but it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what is going on? And, how should I get the progress bar to be able to be clickable?

I didn't see any other code for the playbutton class, and that is why I thought if I copy the same thing it should work, but it doesn't work !

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Comment: why cant you use audio tag ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are binding this to the `a` element, but it has no content in it, therefore you can't click it yet. Maybe bind it to its parents as well:

```
$('#progressBar1, .progressBar, .progress').on('click',function() {
    var progress = document.getElementById("progress1");
    progress.style.width = 70 + "%";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/7c2AR/

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work for me; but what I did instead, I moved the whole function into $(document).ready(function()){ }, and then it started working !?! Why the function needs to be in the "ready" function for it to work?

Comment: @Rudy01 I assumed that you had that working already (it's implemented  by default on JSFiddle). Document ready as the name suggests, means that the DOM is fully loaded. This means the DOM tree is completed, and only then do your elements (which are part of the DOM tree) exist in the page (DOM). Before this, the elements are not yet available.